# empty background-image:url("") remove

Tags: jquery

I want to remove only the `li` that has empty `background-image:url("")`

I tried this but it also remove the other `li` that has `background-image`

```
jQuery("li").each(function(){
  var x = jQuery(this).css("background-image");
  if (x.indexOf("") == 0){
    jQuery(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: @Satpal it doesnt remove anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As background-image is converted to absolute URI, thus `.css("background-image")`  doesn't returns you `url()`/`url("")` so the elements are not matched and removed.

You can create a element with empty background and use it to compare.

```js
// get absolute URI generated by background-image: url()
var image = getImg($('#emptyImageContainer').css("background-image"));

//Filter out desired elements
jQuery("li").filter(function() {
  //Get current element background-image
  var img = getImg(jQuery(this).css("background-image"));

  //if its same as absolute URI means empty
  return image == img;
}).remove();

function getImg(img) {
  return img.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace(/\"/gi, "");;
}
```

```css
.li1 {
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/35c2a1fabdd782080d3c130a65c5504e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1)
}
.empty-image {
  background-image: url()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="li1">1</li>
  <li class="empty-image">2</li>
  <li class="li1">3</li>
</ul>

<div id='emptyImageContainer' class="empty-image"></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkp25mcm/)

Comment: it remove all `li` I dont know why when I console.log the `img` it works and identify that has `background-image`

Comment: should i create a `div`?

Comment: how can i do it? im little confuse on that `div` im trying to remove it and adjust your code that without `div`

Comment: one more question why do i need to add a `div`? and make this `return image == img || img.length == 0;` cant I make it like this `return  img.length == 0;`

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization actually you don need `|| img.length == 0;` I think `return image == img` is enough

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization, to get absolute URI generated by `background-image: url()`

Answer (score 1):

Just try this, It will check all background images, It will also work for broken images as well as blank background-image.

```
jQuery("li").each(function(){
    var item = jQuery(this);
    var x = item.css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1');
      var tester=new Image();
      tester.onerror=imageNotFound;
      tester.src=x;

    function imageNotFound() {
      item.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: still removing all

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x.indexOf('""') > -1){
```

Your current code is searching for the index of an empty string, not two double quotes. Additionally, it probably won't be at position 0.

Comment: it doesnt remove an empty background-image